# chrome is not responding for API response

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

I have one api which is being called from Angularjs from front end, when API hit from post-man it is taking hardly 1 sec to send response, but when it is being called from chrome browser, it leads to hangs it up and Aw, Snap! page.

we are using remote desktop, upon which only chrome is running with a single tab.

Any thoughts we this is happing to us, since api is fine with postman returning a response within 1 sec.

Sample Code of Angular service method, which send the response to controller,

```
this.getData() = function(chartJson) {
    return $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "api/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': "Application/json" },
        data: chartJson
    });
};
```

In controller, we access this above method like,

```
 this.getData()
  .then(function(response){
     console.log(response);
    }, function(error){

        console.log('Error '+error);
  });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show you code where you called up the api

Comment: @jitender, I have updated the body with angular service and controller sample code!!!

Comment: are you getting anything on the console

Comment: this.getData() where are you calling this ?